# David as Blameless: 2 Samuel 22:23-25

Tags: david, 2-samuel, sin

> For all His ordinances were before me, and as for His statues, I did not depart from them. 
>   I was also blameless toward Him, and I kept myself from my iniquity. (2 Samuel 22:23-24 NASB)

We know David was not blameless in the literal sense, and he (when grieving and asking God not to depart from him because of the sin with Bathsheba) certainly recognized this as well. Why would David state that he was blameless towards the Lord, and what does the interesting phrase, “I kept myself from my iniquity” mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David's song in 2 Samuel 22 is almost identical to Psalm 18 which contains the following prelude:

> For the director of music. Of David the servant of the Lord. He sang to the Lord the words of this song when the Lord delivered him from the hand of all his enemies and from the hand of **Saul**.

David wrote this song before the affair of Bathsheba. So the placement of this song in 2 Samuel 22 was not chronologically accurate.

He opened the song with

> 2 “The Lord is my rock, my fortress and my deliverer;
> 3 my God is my rock, in whom I take **refuge**,
> my **shield** and the horn of my salvation.
> He is my stronghold, my refuge and my savior

The following need to be interpreted under the above heading and context:

> For all His ordinances were before me, and as for His statutes, I did not depart from them. I was also **blameless** toward Him, and I kept myself from my iniquity.

Why would David state that he was blameless towards the Lord?

David took refuge in God. That's how he could become blameless. He was shielded by God.

What does the interesting phrase, “I kept myself from my iniquity” mean?

He wrote this before the encounter with Bethsheba. He refused to kill Saul in e.g., 1 Samuel 24:6

> He said to his men, "The LORD forbid that I should do such a thing to my master, the LORD's anointed, or lay my hand on him; for he is the anointed of the LORD."

Another example was Joab killed Abner in cold blood.

> 2 Samuel 3:37
> So on that day all the people there and all Israel knew that the king [David] had no part in the murder of Abner son of Ner.

Another example had to do with Nabal and his men.

> 1 Samuel 25:32 David said to Abigail, “Praise be to the Lord, the God of Israel, who has sent you today to meet me. 33May you be blessed for your good judgment and for **keeping me from bloodshed** this day and from avenging myself with my own hands.

David did try to keep himself from iniquity. He was a conscientious person before God, a man after God's heart.

Answer (score 1):

David is justified (in God's sight) which causes him to be blameless (in God's sight).

> It is God that justifieth, who is he that condemneth ? [Romans 8:33 KJV]

Although not a cause of boasting, but rather a cause of humility, it is still the case that when God justifies, one is justified.

> For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast. [Ephesians 2:8,9 KJV]

But David acknowledges the presence of sin (some call this 'inbred sin') within his own humanity, come of Adam.

> For what the law could not do, in that it was weak through the flesh, God sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, *condemned sin in the flesh*:

Sin in the flesh, being condemned in the humanity of Christ, is taken away :

> Behold the Lamb of God, which taketh away the sin of the world. [John 1:29 KJV]

These things being so, the justified are to pursue holiness :

> Seeing then that all these things shall be dissolved, what manner of persons ought ye to be in all holy conversation and godliness, [2 Peter 3:11 KJV]
>
> That he would grant unto us, that we being delivered out of the hand of our enemies might serve him without fear, In holiness and righteousness before him, all the days of our life. [Luke 1:74, 75 KJV]

David is conscious of the iniquity within his natural humanity, come of Adam, but he keeps himself at a distance from it, by faith.

> I was also upright before him (*being justified by faith*) and I kept myself from mine iniquity (*which still dwells in mortal flesh until the resurrection*) . . . . [Psalm 18:23 KJV]

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer! Could you elaborate a bit on the context of this in the Old Testament? Was David justified in the sense of the above verses, even before the coming of Christ on earth?

Comment: @Gremosa Yes, I believe he was. The first verses of Psalm 32 speak of David's sins being _nasa_ 'uplifted'. Together with the concept of _kaphar_ (_kaph_ the hand of God) David's sins are llifted up from him and 'contained' _kaphar_ by God until such time as the Testator appears who shall bring in the Everlasting Testament by the shedding of his blood. Thus David is justified, righteously, in lieu of a future event. Thus he receives the Holy Spirit as a gift, based on that righteous justification. Compare Romans 4 and Psalm 32.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning it says:

> 1 And David sang this song to the LORD **on the day** the LORD had
> delivered him from the hand of all his enemies and from the hand of
> Saul.
> [Berean Std. 2 Samuel 22:1](https://biblehub.com/bsb/2_samuel/22.htm)

So on that day the incident with Beersheba hadn’t happened yet and David was still blameless.

Answer (score 0):

David was certainly not blameless in terms of "the works of the law", as Paul would say. He was guilty of offences both serious and technical. Adultery. Conspiracy to murder. Neglecting to enforce the law against a rapist (Amnon). Travelling on the sabbath to Nob and eating the shewbread which had been previously been set before the Lord. Reclaiming a wife who had already been passed on to another husband (2 Samuel ch3 vv13-15, compare Deuteronomy ch4 vv1-4).

BUT we do know that in the adultery case, at least, he confessed his sin and repented and was forgiven; "David said to Nathan 'I have sinned against the Lord'and Nathan said to David 'The Lord also has put away your sin; you shall not die'" (2 Samuel ch12 v13). This is the New Testament way of being considered blameless.

Let's compare also what was said about Daniel in Daniel ch6. The lions did not hurt him because he was "found blameless before God" (vv22). Alternatively, the lions did not hurt him because "he had trusted in his God" (v23). These statements may be reconciled on the assumption that "trusting in God" is a legitimate way of "being found blameless".

I propose that David was blameless in the same way that Daniel was blameless. That is, he lived his life trusting in his God, which could be demonstrated from a number of instances as well as from the writing of the Psalms.

In other words, David was saved by his faith, not by his works.

Answer (score 0):

A source-critical approach enables us to understand that the author of this psalm may not actually be David. The passage is practically identical to Psalm 18, also attributed to David.

However, [Lawrence E. Toombs](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/BASOR25609283?journalCode=basor), writing in the Interpreter's Bible, stated:

> The titles of many of the psalms reflect the view which prevailed for
> centuries that David was their author. It is now clear that the theory
> of Davidic authorship cannot be maintained.

Thus the reader need not accept that David is the literal author of the psalm.  An important clue to this effect comes in vs. 7:

> I cried out to my God; From his temple he heard my voice,
> my cry reached his ears.

The temple did not yet exist in David's time, so if David is the actual author, we are forced to think of "his temple" as something other than the plain sense of the text indicates. On the other hand, if we think of the reciter as a pious king of a later period, then both the role of the temple and the speaker's attitude toward his sin make clear sense. Prof. Toombs concluded: "It is a liturgy spoken in the Temple by the King" (but not by David, since the Temple did not yet exist in his lifetime).

**David could not truthfully claim that "as for His statues, I did not depart from them." The best way to understand this statement is therefore that it is a verse written by a temple scribe or priest, to be recited by a pious king of a later era. However, the work was eventually attributed to David.**

Comment: extremely helpful response, with an important reference to verse 7. Thank you!!

Comment: I would add that parts of this song appear to be very ancient. So some speculate that it was partly borrowed from non-Israelite traditions. In terms of which King might have recited it, I would suggest one like Hezekiah, on of the "good kings" who is recorded as praying in the Temple and being healed of a deadly illness.

Answer (score -1):

With the overwhelming influence of the conventional religion which teaches that man is created [defective and depraved](https://theparkprisonministry.org/christian-studies/examining-calvinism/total-depravity-true-or-false/) with [the original sin](https://www.gospeltruth.net/OS100bibleverses.htm), it is hard to convince people that anyone can be sinless. The OP's doubt on David's perfection, however, seems to be presupposing a view of *once a sinner always a sinner*; when the Bible doesn't teach such a gloomy and unrealistic view of the nature of man. If we could not be perfect and sinless, we would be making God a liar who commands to be perfect and go sin no more. And "unless you are converted and become like children, you will not enter the kingdom of heaven", would not have been commanded unless this conversion was possible.

It says "If a man is righteous and does what is just and right—.. walks in my statutes, and keeps my rules by acting faithfully—**he is righteous**; he shall surely live, declares the Lord GOD" (Eze 18) and "Everyone who has this hope set on him purifies himself, even as he is pure. Everyone who sins also commits lawlessness. Sin is lawlessness; **He who does righteousness is righteous**, even as he is righteous" (1 John 3).

- James 3:2 For in many things we all stumble. If anyone doesn’t stumble in word, the same is a perfect man, able to bridle the whole body also.
- 1John 1:9 If we confess our sins, he is faithful and righteous to forgive us the sins, and to **cleanse us from all unrighteousness**.
- Heb 8:12 For I will be merciful to their unrighteousness. I will remember their sins no more." (Isa 43:25, Jer 31:34)
- Isa 1:18 Though your sins are like scarlet, they shall be as white as snow. Though they are red like crimson, they shall be as wool.
- Psa 25:7 Do not remember the sins of my youth, nor my transgressions. Remember me according to your loving kindness, for your goodness' sake, LORD.
- Mic 7:18-19 Who is a God like you, who pardons iniquity, and passes over the disobedience of the remnant of his heritage? He doesn't retain his anger forever, because he delights in loving kindness. He will again have compassion on us. **He will tread our iniquities under foot; and you will cast all their sins into the depths of the sea.**

Therefore, who will bring a charge against God's elect? God is the one who justifies!